# Javascript (or jQuery) string replacement

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace

So, I have strings pulled from a JSON array like this:

```
Hg22+
CO32-
Al3Cl23+
```

These numbers need to be superscript or subscript, with rules.  It's only numbers 0-9, and if that number has a plus or minus after it, it needs to be superscript, meaning I need to change the string to `<sup>3+</sup>`.  All other numbers, if they haven't been superscripted, need to be subscripted.  Here are a few examples of what I need:

`C12H22O11 (s, sucrose)` = `<sub>1</sub><sub>2</sub>H<sub>2</sub><sub>2</sub>O<sub>1</sub><sub>1</sub> (s, sucrose)`

`Al3Cl23+` = `Al<sub>3</sub>Cl<sub>2</sub><sup>3+</sup>`

`Hg22+` = `Hg<sub>2</sub><sup>2+</sup>`

I can do it, but very sloppily.  I am really open to a good way to change string like above.  If anyone can help out I'd be really appreciative!

Thanks!

Comment: How are you currently solving this, and what's wrong with that code? Please edit that into your question.

Comment: I didn't implement it, because I know it would have been completely gross and unwieldy.  Definitely couldn't have used regex on my own, and I knew regex would be by far the best way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy.

```
var result = input.replace(/\d([+-]?)/g,function(match,plus) {
    var s = plus ? "sup" : "sub";
    return "<"+s+">"+match+"</"+s+">";
});
```

Done.

Comment: first blood! XD but you're missing - and g flag

Answer (score 1):

Slightly modified from @[Niet the Dark Absol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507674/niet-the-dark-absol)'s answer

```
var tests = ['Hg22+', 'CO32-', 'Al3Cl23+','C12H22O11 (s, sucrose)'];
function chemize(input) {
  return input.replace(/\d([\+\-]?)/g,function(match,plus) {
    var s = plus ? "sup" : "sub";
    return "<"+s+">"+match+"</"+s+">";
  });  
}
for(var z in tests) {
  var test = tests[z];
  console.log('"' + test + '" --> ' + chemize(test) );
}
```

Output:

```
"Hg22+" --> Hg<sub>2</sub><sup>2+</sup>
"CO32-" --> CO<sub>3</sub><sup>2-</sup>
"Al3Cl23+" --> Al<sub>3</sub>Cl<sub>2</sub><sup>3+</sup>
"C12H22O11 (s, sucrose)" --> C<sub>1</sub><sub>2</sub>H<sub>2</sub><sub>2</sub>O<sub>1</sub><sub>1</sub> (s, sucrose)
```

Comment: Thanks both to you and Niet!  I thought I replied last night, but apparently didn't.  With the addition of the g flag to Niet's code, it was perfect... almost.  As I was analyzing results, I noticed something I didn't catch before.  Sometimes, there will be a plus or minus without a number preceding it.  For example, "Cs+" or "Br- (aq)".  In that case, the plus or minus would also need to be superscripted.  Being that regex stuff makes my eyes go fuzzy, I am curious, what is the difference between your code and Niet's?  Again, I REALLY appreciate the solutions!  Never could have done it...

Comment: there's nothing difference for now, previously his answer lacks of `-` (minus sign) and `g` (global replace)

Comment: you could see his old answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28246776/1